# Pentaho Mondrian- Hide a dimension value from a role

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian, case-when, iif-function

I am using Pentaho Mondrian to build a billing cube with the dimensions "country" and "reference".
**To one of my roles**, I just want to show the reference value when country is equal to "Brazil". If it is not Brazil, reference should be null.

How it is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yipPJ.png

How it should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoF2w.png

How can I do this?

I tryed to use a calculated member with CASE WHEN, but it didn´t work.
Should I use IIF instead?

I code this, but it is not working too:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [dim_reference.Reference].[reference].Members AS 
    IIF
    (
      [dim_country.country].[country].CurrentMember = 'Brazil'
     ,[dim_reference.Reference].[reference].MEMBERS
     ,''
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {Hierarchize({[dim_country.country].[country].MEMBERS})} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      {
        Hierarchize({[dim_reference.Reference].[reference].MEMBERS})
      }
     ,[dim_reference.Reference].CurrentMember.Name
     ,BASC
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [billing_entry];
```

Does someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1

So you need to use the `IS` operator if you want to check for equality with a member.

Rather than this:

```
[dim_country.country].[country].CurrentMember = 'Brazil'
```

You use the following - you might need to amend the RHS with the exact full name of your Brazil member:

```
[dim_country.country].[country].CurrentMember 
       IS [dim_country.country].[country].[country].[Brazil]
```

2

Rather than using `''` you should use `NULL`.

Rather than this:

```
IIF(
      <condition>
     ,<if condition true>
     ,''
    )
```

You should use this:

```
IIF(
      <condition>
     ,<if condition true>
     ,NULL
    )
```

3

You're correct to use `IIF` rather than `CASE` if at all possible - `IIF` *generally* performs better.

---

From your screenshots it looks to me that you want Countries `ON ROWS` rather than `ON COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [dim_country.country].[country].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [billing_entry];
```

Now using `SSAS` against the `AdvWrks` cube I can do this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS 
    IIF
    (
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember
      IS 
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]
     ,[Product].[Product Categories].CurrentMember.Name
     ,null
    ) 
  SET [s] AS 
      [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country]
    * 
      [Product].[Product Categories].[category] 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product Categories].[All].[calc] AS 
    [Product].[Product Categories].CurrentMember.Name 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[X]} ON 0
 ,[s] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Which results in this:

[image]